# What printable characters sequence cannot be found in HTTP dump?

Tags: http

I would like to use such sequence to indicate start of placeholder in text file, that will contain modified dump of http traffic.

For example, if $ would be such character, then I could write

...
GET ${path} HTTP/1.1
...

in file, and I could always recognize, that ${path} was not part of true request (because such sequence is illegal in this place), therefore it must be placeholder.

It's easy to come up with such sequence for headers, however I do not know what is illegal sequence in body.

Character sequence must be printable and easily writable (I would like to avoid writing hacky unicode characters with left alt and numerical keyboard).

Comment: all printable (and actually non-printable) characters can be found in http dump

Comment: I thought so, thats why I am looking for illegal _sequence_

Comment: any sequence is legal too

Comment: Ummm I am not quite sure about it. If it would be true, then how would you distinguish head-body separator from payload within header?

Comment: http standard says that first double line ending (`\n\n`) is the separator, but body can contain multiple ones without any problem